# Capturing System-level Keystrokes with Adobe AIR

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

As the title suggests, is it possible to capture system-level keystrokes?
Any help or pointers will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in Flex using **NativeProcess** once it's added. Check out AIR 2.0 Native Process on [gotoandlearn](http://www.gotoandlearn.com).

Comment: Hi Mahir

Yes i guess we'll have to go that route.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You mean while the app doesn't have focus?

This isn't implemented in AIR currently, but is in the wishlist.

Comment: Yeah, that's right... well, i know it can't be done with AIR directly, but do you know of any cross-platform libraries for keystroke capturing?

Comment: I don't know of a cross platform one, there's plenty of Windows ones out there... Google about for "Hot Key" applications

Answer (score 0):

Danny and myself are working on this project together.

Would it be posssible to use another cross platorm app that can run on Windows, OSX and Linux which can capture keystroke events in while runnning in the background and then tell AIR that a key has been pressed?